# Blank/empty pages Cart and Checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We’re just getting started with WooCommerce and are preparing a store with just a few categories and products in it to play around with it and get to know it before we get seriously into it.

We don’t yet have an SSL certificate for our website.

Does this mean that we won’t be able to create a store and test it until we get an SSL certificate?

As is, we’re seeing blank pages when we go to cart and try to go to checkout. On those pages, our header is there, but the page below the header is empty, blank.

I posted this same question in an existing thread that mentioned this, but haven’t had a reply. Thought maybe it might be missed in that other thread.

maybe, can you see do code shablon this page?

Thank you.

Comment: After googling your question it shows a question exactly the same. Have you check this? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/blankempty-pages-cart-and-checkout/

Comment: It didn't help me!

Comment: Do you know the cart output code in the template?

Comment: How it didn't help you? Please give more information about your Woocommerce setup. Have you tried using the shortcodes? WC shows any king of error message? Do you enabled debug mode?

Comment: Shortcodes are used. Where to view error messages? Debug mode enabled

Comment: I think I figured out what the reason is! I do not work shortcodes in WordPress pages, if you insert shortcodes in the template it works! How to fix it?

Comment: Help me please?

Answer (score 7):

I came across this issue while writing a custom WooCommerce theme from scratch. I realized that if your theme has a page.php template (or any of the fall-back templates in the [WP hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/)) - you **need** to make sure, that `the_content();` function gets called in the template that your `page` post-type is going to use (either `page.php`, `singular.php` or `index.php`) - if you are using the standard WooCommerce setup.

If not, the WooCommerce short-codes are simply never output - which the `cart`, `checkout`, `my-account` and `order-tracking` pages depend on.

Comment: ^ THIS! I am playing around with making a new theme and my index.php didn't have any wp_content(). After that it's solved!

Answer (score 6):

Make sure to enter the [woocommerce_cart] shortcode in the Cart page and [woocommerce_checkout] shortcode on the checkout page. 
And Goto Woocommerce settings and set the Cart Page, Checkout page.
This should solve the issue.

Meanwhile, check the Woocommerce -> System Status and look for errors.
If you are using any page builder, make sure you enter the Shortcodes in the text box modules.
If you still face the issue, try reverting back to Gutenburg editor or classic editor instead of Page builder.

**How to debug:**

[wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-debug-issues-after-updates](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-debug-issues-after-updates)

Perhaps it would be easier to find what is causing the conflict. Try temporarily switching back to the WordPress Twenty Sixteen Theme, or Storefront, and disable all plugins except for WooCommerce. If that resolves the issue, then slowly re-enable features until you find the one that’s causing the conflict

Comment: I think I figured out what the reason is! I do not work shortcodes in WordPress pages, if you insert shortcodes in the template it works! How to fix it?

Comment: Try entering the shortcode in the plain text editor. Not in the WYSIWYG editor.
Are you using any page builder plugin?

Comment: How to debug: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-debug-issues-after-updates

Perhaps it would be easier to find what is causing the conflict. Try temporarily switching back to the WordPress Twenty Sixteen Theme, or Storefront, and disable all plugins except for WooCommerce. If that resolves the issue, then slowly re-enable features until you find the one that’s causing the conflict.

Comment: How enabled plain text editor? I don't use page builder plugin!

Comment: Install the Classic Editor plugin. 
Before that Try temporarily switching back to the WordPress Twenty Sixteen Theme, or Storefront, and disable all plugins except for WooCommerce. If that resolves the issue, then slowly re-enable plugin one by one until you find the one that’s causing the conflict.

Comment: I do switching back to the WordPress Twenty Sixteen Theme everything works there! if I disable all plugins in my theme, nothing works for me, the site is not displayed

Comment: So the issue might be with the theme. Which theme are you using currently?

Now revert back to your current theme and try to disable all plugins except Woocommerce and see if it works.
This might be also because of a plugin conflict with the theme.

Comment: I use a custom template! how to make everything work?

Comment: Leave the theme as it as and disable all the plugins except woocommerce. If that solves the issue, then try reactivating the plugin one by one to find the issue(plugin).

Comment: This is impossible! The site stops working! Just tell me how to enable support for shortcodes and woocommerce?

Comment: By default, Woocommerce plugin shortcodes should work with every theme. If deactivating all the plugins stops the site from working then try disabling the plugins one by one and see which plugin is causing the issue. To find an issue, you need to debug.

Comment: Just to make sure you have added woocommerce support for the theme, add the below code in your functions.php

function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
 add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );

Comment: All other shortcodes working? Related products, featured products shortcode?

Comment: Share the website URL

Comment: All shortcodes don't work! I don't know if your site will open or not!  http://dev-working.ru/gazobeton-backup-27012020/cart/

Comment: Cart & checkout page is already there on the website. 
Cart Page: http://dev-working.ru/gazobeton-backup-27012020/cart/
Checkout Page: http://dev-working.ru/gazobeton-backup-27012020/checkout/

Comment: Rajeev, Good Day! I solved the problem, the problem was the wrong template for the recycle bin and other pages!

Comment: This is best answer if you replace a Visual editor with Elementor.